# This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type 'unit []' for Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously

Tags: f#

I have the following code in the main function of an F# console application.

```
let main ... = 
    let list = // get a list
    list 
    |> Seq.iter(fun i -> ....)
    ()
```

Then I tried to run the items in parallel.

```
let list = // get a list
list 
|> Seq.map(fun i -> async { .... })
|> Seq.toArray
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously // ERROR
// |> ignore
()
```

And it got the error of

```
Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'unit'    
but here has type
    'unit []'
```

Adding `|> ignore` will cause F# not to run the code in the `Seq.map()`.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it but I'm afraid I can't. There's something subtle happening that's not apparent from what you've posted. Did you put your parallel logic inside your main function too? Or did you create a new function for it?

Comment: It's a new function

Comment: There's definitely a lot more going on in the background than what's in the question. If that second code block is the entirety of your new function, then the ``()`` will cause it to return a ``unit`` anyway, not a ``unit []``, so the error message doesn't make sense. I also tried putting in the ``|> ignore`` to the function, and it still iterated through the ``Seq.map`` correctly (I only did ``printfn "%i" i``, but it did it).

Comment: What made you think that adding `ignore` will prevent `Seq.map` from running?

Answer (score 2):

I intentionally will not answer your question per se. Instead, I'll share an approach that you may use to the rescue if you occasionally stumble over asynchronous workflows. The trick is to fully embrace the exploratory programming style that F# promotes.

Let's begin with a minimal async workflow, which may be `async { () }`. Evaluating in FSI

```
let dummywf = async { () }
```

yields

```
val dummywf : Async<unit>
```

showing that `dummywf` value is an async workflow, indeed (although a really dummy one).

Async workflows may be composed into sequences, one of simplest may be the list `[ dummywf ]`. Evaluating it reveals the type `Async<unit> list`, which represents the sought-for one.

Now, let's recall the signature of [`Async.Parallel` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.parallel%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D), which is `seq<Async<'T>> -> Async<'T[]>`, i.e. it takes a sequence of async computations and turns it into an async computation that, being eventually evaluated via asynchronously evaluating its members will yield an array of values of `'T`. Checking in FSI, the expression

```
[ dummywf ] |> Async.Parallel
```

evaluates into a value of type `Async<unit []>`, indeed.

Finally, let's materialize this value by composing it with the simplest form of [`Async.RunSynchronously<'T>` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.runsynchronously%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D)  taking an Async<'T> (in our case a value of type`Async<unit []>`) and returning the result of evaluation of type `'T` (in our case `unit []`. Evaluating the combined expression

```
[ dummywf ] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

yields `[|()|]` as expected.

After getting a crystal clear understanding of the above composition that behaves as expected, but is a way too simple for demonstrating that we really built a full-blown async workflow, let's try something still simple, but more impressive. Let's implement a function of type `int -> Async<unit>` that takes an `int` argument, makes a non-blocking pause, returns the same `unit` and as a side effect prints the value of the argument:

```
let wasteSomeTime x =
    async {
        do! Async.Sleep(100)
        printfn "%d" x
    }
```

Now let's use `wasteSomeTime` to compose a sequence of async computations with distinct arguments and evaluate it within a composition similar to the one in the previous case:

```
let wasteful = [1..10] |> Seq.map wasteSomeTime // binds to seq<Async<unit>>
wasteful |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
```

The output will be resembling

```
> 
4
2
3
6
8
10
7
5
9
1
val it : unit = ()
```

that makes evident the asynchronous execution, indeed.

After grokking the bits and pieces of the small exploratory session above I'm positive you'll be able to answer your original question by yourself.

Comment: I thought my code should behave like this. However, it worked differently after I converted it. The code call functions which call functions which do http requests. Maybe the web server behaves differently with a lot of requests.

Comment: So explore it then! Try to poke at it in different modes and see what happens.